# Android NullPointerException in create comunication listener between Fragment and Activity

Tags: android

I want to create simple communication Listener between Fragment and Activity, after define listener in Activity and implemented that from Fragment I get `NullPointerException` when I send String from Activity to Fragment, I want to send data from `onActivityResult`.

My activity is:

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity {
    public IonGetBarcodeFromScannerListener ionGetBarcodeFromScannerListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        G.currentActivity = this;
        G.context = getBaseContext();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            Log.e("barcode is: ", scanContent);
            doSendBarcode(scanContent);
        }
        else{
            Log.e("No scan data received! ", "");
            doSendBarcode("");
        }
    }

    public void doSendBarcode(String barcode){
        ionGetBarcodeFromScannerListener.getBarcode(barcode);
    }
    public void setBarcodeListener(IonGetBarcodeFromScannerListener l){
        ionGetBarcodeFromScannerListener = l;

    }
    public interface IonGetBarcodeFromScannerListener {
        public void getBarcode(String barcode);
    }
}
```

i get `NullPointerException` for this line:

```
ionGetBarcodeFromScannerListener.getBarcode(barcode);
```

My Fragment:

```
public class FragmentAddNewWayBill extends Fragment implements ActivityMain.IonGetBarcodeFromScannerListener{
    private PtrClassicFrameLayout mPtrFrame;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        G.currentActivity = FragmentAddNewWayBill.this.getActivity();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_waybill, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void getBarcode(String barcode) {
        Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "salam: " + barcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying for activity and fragment communication in opposite way as I think interface will be defined in fragment and it's implementation will be done in activity. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html for more details

Comment: I guess this [link](http://infobloggall.com/2014/06/22/communication-between-activity-and-fragments/) will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are never calling `setBarcodeListener()` so the field is never set, and therefore `null`.

-- update --

You could call it inside the fragment's `onAttach()` by using the return value from `.getActivity()`.

Comment: yes i know it, but i can not set in inside Fragment. can you more help how to set it?

Comment: how to create new instance from created Listener in Activity inside Fragment sir?